# Finding the value of $\prod_{n=0}^\infty a_n$ with $a_0=1/2$ and $a_{n}=1+(a_{n-1}-1)^2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, infinite-product

[image]

Putting the value of the first term, we can see that the series goes like
$$1/2, 5/4, 17/16,...$$ 
I am unable to calculate the general term, and so not sum of the series. Please help me to find the general term or directly the infinite sum if possible.

Comment: Not a sum.  A product.  The "summation " symbol is $\Pi$ instead of $\Sigma$; the latter means "sum" but the former means "product".

Comment: oh....thank you

Comment: Looks like denominators (starting at $n=0$) are $2^{2^n}$ and numerators are 1 more than denominators. Just a guess... and I've no idea about the product of all these.

Maybe this should be made into a comment. OK if someone wants to, o just inform me and I'll do that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let $b_n=a_n-1$ so that $b_0=-\frac 12$ and $b_{n}=b_{n-1}^2$.
Consequently, $b_n=b_0^{2^n}$ hence
$$a_n=1+(-2)^{-2^n}$$
Let $x=\frac 12$, then
\begin{align}
(1+x)\prod_{n=0}^Na_n
&=(1+x)\prod_{n=0}^N(1+(-x)^{2^n})\\
&=(1+x)(1-x)(1+x^2)\cdots(1+x^{2^N})\\
&=(1-x^2)(1+x^2)\cdots(1+x^{2^N})\\
&=(1-x^4)(1+x^4)\cdots(1+x^{2^N})\\
&=(1-x^8)(1+x^8)\cdots(1+x^{2^N})\\
&=\cdots\\
&=(1-x^{2^N})(1+x^{2^N})\\
&=1-x^{2^{N+1}}\\
&\xrightarrow{N\to\infty}1
\end{align}
so that
$$\prod_{n=0}^\infty a_n=\frac 23$$

Comment: Beautiful solution, for sure ! Thanks for providing it and $+1$.